# Box plot ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need to plot a BoxPlot by hour (from 0 to 23) with outliers using the following data:

```
Val1    DateTime
16.0    2021-08-02 09:00:00
541.0   2021-08-02 10:00:00
576.0   2021-08-02 11:00:00
2080.0  2021-08-02 12:00:00
4358.0  2021-08-02 13:00:00
...
124.0   2021-08-30 23:00:00
```

This is how I do it:

```
df.set_index(df.DateTime.dt.hour, append=True)["Val1"].unstack().plot.box(figsize=(15,5))
```

But get this error:

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

I don't want to drop duplicated hours because for each hour I have multiple values and I want to see how these values are distributed.

**Update:**

If I use `iloc[0:500]` it works well. If I use `iloc[500:1000]`, the it also works well. But if I run with `iloc[0:1000]`, it throws an error.

Comment: I created the sample data and ran your code and no error was generated and 24 boxplots were drawn. Is the date and time column in datetime format?

Comment: @r-beginners Yes, it in `datetime64[ns]` format. If I only select, say 100 rows, then it works. But it gives this error on the complete dataset.

Comment: What version of pandas do you use? I checked with the latest version (1.3.4).

Comment: @r-beginners: I use pandas 1.1.5. Please see an update. Could it be because of the threshold of rows for a box plot?

Comment: To test more than 1,000 cases, we expanded the data to 1417 cases in 24 hours from Aug. 2 to Sept. 30 to support The graphs were displayed correctly. Are there any duplicate data in your time series data itself?

Comment: Try this: `df[df.duplicated(subset='Datetime') == True]`

Comment: @r-beginners I finally did it with seaborn without unstacking. Thanks.